# Managing a large SPSS (*.sav) file (4.2 GB)

Tags: csv, spss, pspp

I have received an SPSS file from survey fielded by another company that allegedly only contains ~1500 respondents, but the file size somehow has ballooned 4.2GB. My hunch is that the reason for this is that the file was from a global survey and the 1500 records that have been selected are from the US only so there are a series of blank variables, metadata for those variables that are included in this file and may also be in multiple languages/alphabets.

I only need a subset of this data, and can likely work with it if I removed the metadata but my issue has been that I can't get the damn thing open to cut down on the number of variables. I have been using the tools at my disposal to try the following workarounds, though I'm sure there are better options:

1. Opening the file using PSPP (freeware SPSS) - this causes the PSPP to stop responding
2. Using the R command read.spss (from the foreign package) to write a .csv - this claims that the file has a duplicate variable name and won't proceed further
3. Using the R command spss.system.file to write a .csv - when I tried this, R has spend a lot of time thinking as it as it attempts to run this and has been running for a couple hours with no apparent success.
4. Using the PSPP text conversion tool (https://pspp.benpfaff.org/) to create either a dictionary or a .csv file - both of these options crash after the file has completed uploading.

I've gone back to the other company to try have them work on reducing the file size, however I wasn't sure if anyone else had any ideas to do either of the following:

- Open the file using another program/converter that could turn it into a .csv or other similarly skinny file format
- Use another program to at least read only the variable names included in the file so that I can provide the other company with the specific variables I need

Answer (score 1):

The following command from PSPP should do what you need:

```
$ pspp-convert originalFile.sav output.csv
```

In case it doesn't, please provide terminal error message.

Comment: I think that what you've suggested should work, but any time I've tried to use command line here, I've had an issue with "duplicate" variable names. I have been able to finally open the document - but have been unable to manipulate it due to the file size once it's open. None of the variable names appear to be duplicates - though many of them are very long names.      
`S18013542.sav' near offset 0x6d8c4: Renaming variable with duplicate name B1_LO1QM' to 'VAR101'.
Warnings (101) exceed limit (100).  Syntax processing will be halted.`

Comment: How was the *.sav file generated? was it saved from pspp? spss? manually generated?